# Operation to "Get and AND" boolean variable in Java

Tags: java

Is it possible in Java to use syntax like (`i++`, `++i`) for boolean logic operators?

I have a boolean variable that is true only for the first iteration of a `foreach` loop. That iteration has to be skipeed.

Full syntax is

```
for (...)
{
    if (bool)
    {
        bool &= false;
        continue;
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is any way to shorten the syntax *without using `AtomicBoolean`*. For example construct `if (bool &= false)` is syntactically correct but I think it will compare the final result and not the original value.

Google is not my friend because the search query is misleading

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by `bool &= false;` that is not achieved by `bool = false;`?

Comment: Maybe you can use a different loop and/or initialisation to skip the special treatment for the edge case entirely. Could you please provide some more information on what makes the first iteration so special? How and why is it different to the other iterations?

Comment: Why _without using `AtomicBoolean`_?

Comment: @glglgl because AtomicBoolean exposes a method `getAndSet` which is **exactly** what I want. Sometimes creative questions on SO are born by curiosity on topic

Comment: @djechelon Ah, ok. My suggestion would have been to use `AtomicBoolean`, so I was curious about this exclusion.

Comment: Haha, it seems like Java is an immorale language: There is no definition saying that true is higher than false. So this is why incrementing a boolean is not defined. Do I increase to true when been false or to false when I have been right? So incrementing in the case that I was right would cause a buffer overflow because there is nothing higher than true and there would be no distinction between incrementing true and decrementing it.

Comment: But if you need a sort of toggeling, you can still do that using boolean operators : bool = !bool

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Personally I would simplify your current code to:

```
for (...)
{
    if (bool)
    {
        bool = false;
        continue;
    }
    // Rest of code
}
```

... but if you *really* want to do it in the `if` condition as a side-effect, you could use:

```
for (...)
{
    if (bool && !(bool = false))
    {
        continue;
    }
    // Rest of code
}
```

Here the first operand of the `&&` operator covers subsequent operations, and `!(bool = false)` will always evaluate to `true` *and* set `bool` to false.

Another option, from comments:

```
for (...)
{
    if (bool | (bool = false))
    {
        continue;
    }
    // Rest of code
}
```

This performs the assignment on each iteration, but it still gives the right result each time.

I *really, really* wouldn't use either of these last two options though.

Comment: `bool | (bool = false)` would be even more compact

Comment: @HenriViik: Ah yes, good point - will add that as another option.

Answer (score 22):

Your code is the usual thing to do. However, there's an alternative:

```
for (SomeType thing : Iterables.skip(things, 1)) {
    // process thing
}
```

This uses Google Guava's [`Iterables.skip()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#skip-java.lang.Iterable-int-) method and produces your expected output - a for-each loop iterating over the collection and skipping the first element.

Comment: @Constantin, meh. Guava is so popular that any reasonably large project will likely already include it. I do agree that any library-dependent answer (unless the OP mentions such) is a secondary answer however.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, just use an integer variable and use `++` to post-increment it.

```
int iter = 0;
for (...) {
    if (iter++ == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    ...
}
```

If you want to skip the first iteration, this might even be easier to understand.

Comment: Assuming you aren't doing enough iterations to get an overflow

Answer (score 5):

Don't use increments for boolean types If you must use a boolean, either toggle it, such as `!bool`, or just set it to false:

```
for (...){
    if (bool) {
        bool = false;
        continue;
    }
}
```

Ideally, if all you want is to skip the first, last or nth iteration, do not use a boolean at all but an int instead ...

```
    int skipIndex = 0;
    for(int index=0; index < 5; index++){
        if(index != skipIndex) {
            System.out.println(index);
        }
    }
```

... or the following to only skip the first iteration:

```
    int[] values = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    for (int index = 1; index < values.length; index++) {
        System.out.println(values[index]);
    }
```

Comment: And how exactly would he use `!bool` to make his code example shorter?

Comment: I think a `while` loop would be an alternative if OP would be using `break`, but how does it help with skipping the first iteration?

Comment: I dont agree with your stance on `continue`, `break` and particularly on `return`.

Answer (score 4):

If (and only if) you are really so certain that you will *always* need to continue on the first iteration, why not just skip that iteration? Instead of starting with `i=0`, start with

```
for(i=1....
```

Comment: I think OP meant foreach, as in for(String str : strArray){...}

Comment: @Marius The java `foreach` syntax is just syntactic sugar. There is nothing stopping you from using traditional `for` loop syntax with a string array.

Comment: @Marius not exactly. When you work with an `Iterator` you cannot use `for (i=...)`, but then you can call `next()` twice :-)

Comment: Sorry I said @ marius but I meant @ DavidGrinberg in my last comment

Comment: @djechelon But you said it yourself, you can just use `iter.next()`. i.e. `for(iter i=strArray.iterator().next();...`. Also @whoever, why the downvote?

Answer (score 4):

I've been struggling to see why the OP is trying to use `bool &= false;` when `bool = false` will obviously do. In that sense, *Jon Skeet*'s answer is (unsurprisingly) correct.

What I think the OP actually wants to do is set the variable to false and test it in one step. That's the reason for the reference to `AtomicBoolean`. It's nothing per-se to do with loops. IE he wants to do the same as:

```
int a=0;
for ( ... ) {
    if (a++ == 0 ) { // works if we aren't doing too many iterations
        continue;
    }
    ...
}
```

i.e. he wants the equivalent of a post-increment operator.

If I'm right, it's not the loop he's worried about, it's the fact that `a` here is being read once, then separately read again.

This is a case of premature optimisation. The Java compiler is very likely (no I haven't tested it) to produce a single read and test and of the code with

```
boolean a=false;
for ( ... ) {
    if (!a) {
        a = true;
        continue;
    }
}
```

as *Jon Skeet* suggested.

The answer (for completeness) is that there is no post-increment operator that works on `boolean` and I couldn't work out how to define a function that does that without at least mentioning the variable twice. However, that should not be a design consideration.

Note in a real `for` loop you can just do:

```
int i;
boolean skip;
for (i=0, skip=true; i<10; i++, skip=false) {
    if (skip)
        continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0, boolean doIt = false; i < 10; i++, doit = true) {
    if (doIt) {
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: some kind of explanation woudl be helpful.

Comment: As StackOverflow undoubtedly told you in a big, red balloon: `Please add some context to explain the code sections.`